# Pug-Jade template accessing modules data

Tags: javascript, pug

Edit : I'm trying to create a pug-jade template in which a table is created, the first row of the table is static (i.e some headers ) for each subsequent row i want to add an employee. I have 3 files express.js (handels request to my app) employee.js, and index.pug.
Here is what i export in employee.js

```
function Employee (id,name,surname,lvl,salary){
this.id = id;
this.name = name;}
exports.employees = {
employeeList: [],
//the empList is a list of employee defined above, class contains some other methods   
}
```

In the express.js i call :

```
var employees = require('./employees')
```

inside the request handler i call :

```
res.render('index',{employees: employees})
```

and finally in index.pug i try to :

```
tbody
    for val in employees.employeeList
        td=val.id
        td=val.name
```

And this is the error :

```
TypeError: /Users/filippobosco/Desktop/GitHubRepos/IngSoftware2/Employees/ExpressTutorial/views/index.pug:39   

  37| th Salary
  38| tbody
> 39| for val in employees.employeeList
  40| td=val.id
  41| td=val.name
  42| 

  Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: You've changed your pug code. It used to be `td=val.id` now you've got `td=employeesList.id` which definitely won't work.

Comment: Fixed, that was a type error

Comment: Can you please add an example of what the `employees.js` file looks like? Your error says that `employees` is `undefined` which means it is not importing correctly.

Comment: Please add an actual snippet of code; Don't describe your file.

Answer (score 0):

Your `employees` variable is `undefined`.

This means that there is a problem with your `require('employees')` import. Without being able to see the `employees.js` files, I'd have to guess that you're `exports` are not set up correctly.

Comment: @FilippoBosco I've updated my answer to reflect the changes to your question.

Comment: So even now, after modyfing what i am accessing, it throws the same error!any clue?

Comment: @FilippoBosco your `employees.js` file is not importing correctly, you need to show what that looks like, because your import is coming back undefined.

Comment: Please don't use off-site resources, update your question to include the relevant snippet.

Comment: Only in the .pug file tho, since it's workin correctly in my express.js. Might it be that im doin

Comment: I've edited the question to be more clear and specific. I was wondering too if that export is the problem. Should I module.export?

Comment: Never mind im an idiot, it's for val in employees.employees.employeeList

Answer (score 0):

Once you've dealt with the suggestions above...

I came here from having a similar issue and what worked for me would have been something like this:

```
tbody
for val in employees.employeeList
    td #{val.id}
    td #{val.name}
```

NOTE: I am using pug 3.10.6